# Consistently failing at CSS background images

Tags: css, background, background-image

I have managed to learn html & CSS from scratch for the last two weeks. I've had my dark moments with tables and floats but I've always been able to fix problems myself up to this point.

I cannot get the CSS background / background image rule to work, as below:

```
    <div class="mao"></div>

    .mao {
  background: url("mao.png");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
```

I have tried switching between background and background-image. I've tried moving the file into a separate img folder. I've tried various combinations of rules and it never shows. Nor, in-fact do any other images I try to use.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try adding some text to the div tag (or any content), or give it a width and height because unless it's filled with something, it won't display its background (or being shown in the screen)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background image to show without any text, you need to set the height in your class properties.

```
<style>
    .mao{
        background: url("mao.jpg");
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        height: 300px; /*or whatever height you want*/
        }
</style>
```

And then:

```
<div class="mao"></>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check out [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) details about background property of css